# PIL.Image vs skimage.io: When to use each, and which (if one) is prefered over the other in general?

Tags: python, image-processing, package

I have been using Image for opening and getting pixel info, and have read things like "PIL is the future and blabla..", but I have seen that skimage is extensively used.

Which one should I use for general image processing? I would feel more comfortable with this question answered..

Comment: They have rather different focuses. What kind of image processing do you need?

Comment: I'm developing some filtering algorithms like morphologic opening and closing, and Perona for anisotropic diffusion. Some point operations like Otsu for binary segmentation too. All of them for college. As I am developing them on my own, I suppose that I'm going 'generic', if you accept the term.

Comment: I am not an expert on this, but in my limited experience, I find it annoying to convert back and forth between PIL images and numpy arrays. Whereas, skimage format is compatible with numpy arrays (as is opencv). So I tend to avoid PIL, if I can.

Comment: @fmw42 raises a good point. I've found that skimage and skvideo are stronger for machine learning and algorithmic type of work in which you need to access the image's internal array structure. PIL is more of a high level image library.

Answer (score 2):

In general it is safe to say that `Pillow` *(install this rather than `PIL` as `Pillow` is maintained)* is the one to go for if you are manipulating Image->Image as this is its main focus.

However, if you are reading an image for manipulation by other science kit based tools, *such as machine learning*, then go for skimage.io or better its replacement `imageio` *thanks to @cris-luengo for pointing this our* and you are likely to have to do less conversion back and forth.

The other consideration is the size:

Results of `pip download scikit-image` to a Windows 64 machine:

```
21/10/2022  06:20         3,363,278 imageio-2.22.2-py3-none-any.whl
21/10/2022  06:20         2,023,640 networkx-2.8.7-py3-none-any.whl
21/10/2022  06:20        14,643,698 numpy-1.23.4-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
21/10/2022  06:20            40,750 packaging-21.3-py3-none-any.whl
21/10/2022  06:20         3,276,402 Pillow-9.2.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
21/10/2022  06:20            98,338 pyparsing-3.0.9-py3-none-any.whl
21/10/2022  06:20         4,162,789 PyWavelets-1.4.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
21/10/2022  06:20        12,044,719 scikit_image-0.19.3-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
21/10/2022  06:20        40,141,232 scipy-1.9.3-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
21/10/2022  06:20           210,312 tifffile-2022.10.10-py3-none-any.whl
              10 File(s)     80,005,158 bytes
```

Results of `pip download Pillow` to a Windows 64 machine:

```
21/10/2022  06:22         3,276,402 Pillow-9.2.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
```

Note that the download of `scikit-image` includes `Pillow` as a dependency so you are going to be "using" Pillow whichever way you go but a lot depends on how accessible and in what form it is accessible.

If you are going for the `Scipy` route anyway you are likely to need all *or most* of that 80 MB but if you are not then Pillow at 3 MB is a much lighter space commitment.

Comment: `skimage.io` is deprecated, and is simply an interface to `imageio`. This one in turn depends on Pillow and some other packages to read and write image files. `imageio` is very nice though.

Comment: I checked today (3/2/2023) and scikit-image seems to be under active development. Link to URL: https://scikit-image.org/. Their website today states "Release! Version 0.20.0 2023-02-28" under News. Given this information, I am not sure what to make of statement by @CrisLuengo.

Comment: @user3613932 `skimage` is in active development. But the `skimage.io` submodule is to be dropped. They are recommending you use the `imageio` package instead. See https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/5036